# refresh b content using ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dis() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("bell").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    
    dis();
    setInterval(function() {
            dis();
    }, 5000) 

</script>
```

```html
<a id="coll" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#togglePages">
 <i class="menu-icon icon-cog"></i>
 <i class="icon-chevron-down pull-right"></i><i class="icon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
 Order Management
 <b class="label orange pull-right"></b>
</a>
```

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$status = 'Delivered';                                   
$ret1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Orders where orderStatus!='$status' || orderStatus is null ");
$num1 = mysqli_num_rows($ret1);
echo $num1;
?>
```

I need to refresh counter every update happen in the table in the database I try this code but it didn't work for me

what the wrong in this code?

Comment: did u tried your query in phpmyadmin directly? `SELECT * FROM Orders where orderStatus!='Delivered' || orderStatus is null`

Comment: yes and it work

Comment: `<b class="label orange pull-right"></b>` i think u forgot to add `ID=bell` here

Comment: still didn't work

Comment: is your script placed before html???

Comment: check your browser console, what not working, what error are u getting?

Comment: what error are u getting ?? check browser console

Comment: What was the issue? Please share the solution if applicable so others coming here with similar problems may get an answer.